# Using attribute table values as input for raster calculation in ModelBuilder with iteration?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, iterator

I have multiple years of daily XY point shapefiles that contains multiple attributes.  I would like to choose one attribute from my XY point and perform a raster calculation with that value and apply it to a raster to create a new raster.  For example, my XY point is a base station for temperature and I would like to associate temperature with elevation (using a DEM as my raster).

The raster calculation would go something like this:

*New raster temp = shapefile temp + (6.5 * (shapefile elev – DEM elev))*

Each day has a different temperature.  I have been unsuccessful so far in creating a model to perform this action on one day, let alone iterating through multiple days, without having to manually enter in my attribute value (temperature) into the calculation.  Raster calculation manually will become very tedious over 2000 days…

Does anyone have any suggestions for a tool or sequence of tools that I may have overlooked, and especially how to get it working iteratively in ModelBuilder?

Comment: is there a common field between the shapefiles that can be used to table join them? If not I believe you could do a spatial join and join the point data to the raster grid (choose which way you want the data attached, ie sum, max value, etc...)  once you have joined the tables then just use the algorithm you provided to calculate the new temp

Comment: @ed.hankins - thank you for your suggestions.  I actually separated my data due to the need for individual daily output.  The goal is to get an ascii grid file of temperature for each day. Regarding the raster calculation, the "spatial join" method is only working for shapefile to shapefile, not shapefile to raster.  I should probably clarify that I want to start with a raster (a DEM), but link a shapefile attribute table value (temperature) as one of my raster calculation inputs.  Maybe this is not possible?  Maybe raster calculator is not the method of choice for my end goal?

Comment: You can convert your points to raster and then it will be available in the Raster Calculator. However, surely the DEM raster contains more data then the station, wouldn't it be better to stay in the vector world? You can do that by using Extract Values to Points to assign the elevation to the vectors, then use Calculate Field. As an alternative to iterators you can right-click the tool and choose batch (where you can paste values from excel)

Comment: @ed.hankins - Thank you for your suggestions.  The "point to raster" followed by the "raster calculation" worked.  I will add that I have tried this many times before, but made the point to raster cell size the same as my original DEM.  Doing this makes the raster calculation output the size of one DEM gridcell - I wanted the output to expand my whole field area.  So, I just repeated  the above process, but made the point to raster cell size the size of my field area.  Success!!   Now to automate in ModelBuilder...

Comment: glad it worked out for you!